# How to select only OData child elements

Tags: c#, odata

I'm building an OData application and I'm struggling on how to retrieve results and only include certain (child properties).

First, let me show you the registration in my builder:

```
builder.EntitySet<AggregatedArticlesSearchModel>("Search").EntityType.HasKey(x => x.Name);
```

Now, on to the model that I'm returning from my Query:

```
<EntityType Name="AggregatedArticlesSearchModel">
    <Key>
        <PropertyRef Name="Name"/>
    </Key>
    <Property Name="Name" Nullable="false" Type="Edm.String"/>
    <Property Name="Values" Type="Collection(Zevij_Necomij.Mobile.App.Api.Models.OccurenceViewModel)"/>
</EntityType>
<ComplexType Name="OccurenceViewModel">
    <Property Name="Value" Type="Edm.String"/>
    <Property Name="Count" Nullable="false" Type="Edm.Double"/>
    <Property Name="Articles" Type="Collection(Zevij_Necomij.Mobile.App.Api.Models.AggregatedArticleDescriptionViewModel)"/>
</ComplexType>
<ComplexType Name="AggregatedArticleDescriptionViewModel">
    <Property Name="Name" Type="Edm.String"/>
    <Property Name="Specification" Type="Edm.String"/>
    <Property Name="Brand" Type="Edm.String"/>
</ComplexType>
```

When I'm executing a request to get the data, I'm not doing anything fancy but just returning the results from the database:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get()
{
    // Create all the managers for the platform context that are required by the application.
    var classificationManager = Context.CreateManager(typeof(AggregatedArticleManager<>)) as AggregatedArticleManager<IAggregatedArticleStore<AggregatedArticle>>;

    var classifications = await classificationManager.GetAllAsync();

    var returnList = classifications.OrderBy(x => x.Name).Select(AggregatedArticlesSearchModel.MapFromDbModel).ToList();

    return Ok(returnList.AsQueryable());
}
```

Since I'm working with child objects, the list can get quite huge:

```
{
  "@odata.context":     "http://api.mobileapp.appserver.dev.dsoft.be/OData/$metadata#Search",
  "value": [
    {
      "Name": "(Veiligheids)slipkoppeling",
      "Values": [
        {
          "Value": "ja",
          "Count": 118,
      "Articles": [
        {
          "Name": "230 V Sleuvenzaag",
          "Specification": "Compacte machine",
          "Brand": "Makita"
        },
        {
          "Name": "230V Cirkelzaag SJS",
          "Specification": "Softstart voor
        },
    }
}
```

I can have a thousand articles in a single set, thus, way to much to return over the Web Api.
Since I don't need all those properties in a single request, I was thinking to let the cliënt only retrieve child properties by using the `?$select` parameter, thus the cliënts can say for example:

```
OData/Search?$select=Values
```

The problem here is that I for example, only want to return the Count, thus, I tought that a request like this was possible:

```
OData/Search?$select=Values/Count
```

However, this leads to an OData error: `"The query specified in the URI is not valid. Found a path with multiple navigation properties or a bad complex property path in a select clause. Please reword your query such that each level of select or expand only contains either TypeSegments or Properties."`

Anyone who has an idea on how to solve this one?

Answer (score 8):

@Complexity

As I know, to select a sub property in a property is not supported.

However, if you build the `OccurenceViewModel` as entity type, then you can use the nested $select in $expand to meet your requirement.

For example:

1) build the entity type

```
builder.EntitySet<OccurenceViewModel>("ViewModels").EntityType.HasKey(x => x.Value);
```

then, `Values` in `AggregatedArticlesSearchModel` should be a navigation property.

2) Now, you can issue a GET request as follows to only return the Count property:

```
GET ~/odata/Search?$select=Values&$expand=Values($select=Count)
```

Then, the payload should look like the below:

```
{
  "@odata.context":"http://localhost/odata/$metadata#Search(Values,Values(Count))","value":[
    {
      "Values":[
        {
          "Count":101.0
        },{
          "Count":102.0
        }
      ]
    },{
      "Values":[
        {
          "Count":101.0
        },{
          "Count":102.0
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Hope it can help you. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look and come back to you to see if it's working.

Comment: Now, the nested $select in $select is supported. see https://devblogs.microsoft.com/odata/select-enhancement-in-asp-net-core-odata/